# Different kinds of time+spatial data

Tags: time, standards, spatio-temporal-data, terminology

I work on a geospatial aggregator. We support certain kinds of temporal data, but we don't have clear names for the different types, and I don't have a clear understanding of the range of geospatial+temporal data. Is there a definitive classification of types? Even a standard term for each one would be helpful.

For instance, these are either supported or planned:

- raster + time (eg, satellite imagery)
- point in time (eg, earthquakes)
- point with time series (eg, river levels at sensor locations)
- point moving in time (vehicle locations)

And obviously the above could be applied to polygons and lines, to cover things like change in extent of vegetation, or position of a storm front.

And further, some of the above could be combined, like a point moving in time that also has one or more time series associated with it (eg, a sensor mounted on a vehicle).

So:

- **Are there other "spatial + temporal" combinations not included in the above?**
- **What are the definitive terms for each combination?**

Comment: Pebesma has a paper on this: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/spacetime/vignettes/jss816.pdf It's easy to overcook your own defs though, in ways that don't actually work for others

Answer (score 1):

Add to that

- point with time span (an observation valid between two timestamps: from_time and to_time)